# Criteria of creating a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, architecture

Are there good criteria for creating a gem instead of creating another class in the lib folder?

I have worked with a couple of Rails projects, and the codebase tend to be monolithic. I want to to start modularising, but I cannot convince the team and myself from which point we start with creating independent libraries.

For instance, creating a gem for a three-liner class sounds an over-engineering. On the other hand, it seems reasonable because at least that would be 6 lines when comes with tests, and the code might grow further. Also code pieces which does not belong to MVC should not be in the app to be strict in the craftsmanship, but I am not sure yet.

Can you share your experience of your Rail projects, other sources, like books or blog articles, or lessons from projects of other languages?

Comment: spickermann's answer made me think of a set of criteria.

If the well-confined code chunk under the consideration is 
1. reusable in other projects/parts of the application -> Create a gem
2. application specific,
  - And the chunk is small -> Keep the code in the application (because creating/maintaining the gem outweighs).
  - And the chunk is big    -> Create an independent service.

Answer (score 5):

I use to extract gems for different reasons:

- the code solves a common problem and might be helpful to others (open source it)
- you want to reuse the code in different apps, even if these apps do not exist at the moment (e.g. api integrations to internal services)
- is the code reused in totally different areas of my codebase (that is an indicator that it is independent from my app)
- if there is not only one class, but multiple files that depend on each other

IMO it is not about lines of code. It might makes sense to extract an one liner, if it solves a common problem and might help others (think about code extensions in active_support, most of them aren't very complex). And on the other hand it might not makes sense to extract a class with 100+ lines, when it solves only a very specific problem in domain.

If I wanted to break up a monolithic app, I would not look into the lib folder. I would look at the app itself, and would try extract bigger parts into smaller services.

Comment: Breaking an app into several services is surely necessary. But creating independent packages is another tool. Also we can consider that not adding new functionalities to the mothership is a gentler and far easier step.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a gem for a 3 line class is over-engineering. It will create more overhead than it's worth. Look into engines as well but premature modularization and/or optimization can make a bigger mess than a concise monolithic app IMO.